# Swift socket io client fail to connect to socket io nodejs server

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, socket.io

I am using v4 of socket-io nodejs server. I am using v16 of swift socket-io client.

```
static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: baseUrl)!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
 let socket: SocketIOClient? = manager.defaultSocket
```

Then in `onAppear` Property of `SwiftUI` view I have written following code

```
socket?.connect()
            
            
            socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
                print("socket connected")
            }
            
            socket?.on("userjoined", callback: { (data, ack) in
                debugPrint("here")
                debugPrint("\(data)")
                statusText = data[0] as? String ?? ""
            })
            
            socket?.on("receiveMessage", callback: { (data, ack) in
                debugPrint("here12")
                debugPrint("\(data)")
                let str = data[0] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                viewModel.msgsList.append("\(String(describing: str["title"])) \(String(describing: str["email"]))")
            })
            
            socket?.on("disconnected", callback: { (data, ack) in
                debugPrint("here34")
                debugPrint("\(data)")
            })
```

I get following logs

```
022-05-03 15:41:56.587211+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
2022-05-03 15:41:56.681857+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
2022-05-03 15:41:56.684175+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
2022-05-03 15:41:56.684517+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2022-05-03 15:41:56.698649+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
2022-05-03 15:41:56.698744+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: https://MY_URL.com
2022-05-03 15:41:56.698994+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2022-05-03 15:41:56.699101+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: userjoined
2022-05-03 15:41:56.699300+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: receiveMessage
2022-05-03 15:41:56.699506+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: disconnected
2022-05-03 15:41:56.706344+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET https://MY_URL.com/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4
2022-05-03 15:41:58.570648+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-05-03 15:41:58.622922+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-05-03 15:41:58.933217+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2022-05-03 15:41:58.934444+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 0{"sid":"JD6xrLvEJvsDy233AAAO","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}
2022-05-03 15:41:58.937097+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"JD6xrLvEJvsDy233AAAO","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}
2022-05-03 15:41:58.959116+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketManager: Engine opened Connect
2022-05-03 15:41:58.959234+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET https://MY_URL.com/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4&sid=JD6xrLvEJvsDy233AAAO
2022-05-03 15:41:58.960781+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll: 0/, has data: false
2022-05-03 15:41:58.961072+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll: 0/, as type: 4
2022-05-03 15:41:58.963670+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 40/,
2022-05-03 15:41:58.966090+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2022-05-03 15:41:58.966287+0530 ws-ios[18838:339267] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling POST https://MY_URL.com/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4&sid=JD6xrLvEJvsDy233AAAO
2022-05-03 15:41:59.897212+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-05-03 15:41:59.902511+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-05-03 15:42:00.362048+0530 ws-ios[18838:339283] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2022-05-03 15:42:00.362379+0530 ws-ios[18838:339283] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 40{"sid":"m_m3eV5SRygPv4inAAAP"}
2022-05-03 15:42:00.362691+0530 ws-ios[18838:339283] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 40{"sid":"m_m3eV5SRygPv4inAAAP"}
2022-05-03 15:42:00.363351+0530 ws-ios[18838:339283] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET https://MY_URL.com/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4&sid=JD6xrLvEJvsDy233AAAO
2022-05-03 15:42:00.363967+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketParser: Parsing 0{"sid":"m_m3eV5SRygPv4inAAAP"}
2022-05-03 15:42:00.370844+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketParser: Decoded packet as: SocketPacket {type: 0; data: [{
    sid = "m_m3eV5SRygPv4inAAAP";
}]; id: -1; placeholders: -1; nsp: /}
2022-05-03 15:42:00.371973+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Socket connected
2022-05-03 15:42:00.372224+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connected, 3]
2022-05-03 15:42:00.378048+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: connect with data: ["/", ["sid": m_m3eV5SRygPv4inAAAP]]
2022-05-03 15:42:00.378370+0530 ws-ios[18838:339283] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws: probe as type: 2
socket connected
2022-05-03 15:42:00.381198+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["Sec-WebSocket-Accept": "hO9PSta7ypMVlBDHEuYM6iZRCD4=", "Connection": "Upgrade", "Upgrade": "websocket", "Via": "1.1 vegur"]]
2022-05-03 15:42:00.618775+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3probe
2022-05-03 15:42:00.619336+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEngine: Received probe response, should upgrade to WebSockets
2022-05-03 15:42:00.619731+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEngine: Upgrading transport to WebSockets
2022-05-03 15:42:00.620094+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 6
2022-05-03 15:42:00.620489+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 6
2022-05-03 15:42:00.621049+0530 ws-ios[18838:339266] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2022-05-03 15:42:00.621621+0530 ws-ios[18838:338830] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: pong with data: []
2022-05-03 15:42:00.723890+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2022-05-03 15:42:00.724828+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 6
2022-05-03 15:42:00.725858+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 6
2022-05-03 15:42:00.726999+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] LOG SocketEngine: Switching to WebSockets
2022-05-03 15:42:00.727463+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws:  as type: 5
2022-05-03 15:42:00.727999+0530 ws-ios[18838:339277] LOG SocketEngine: Flushing probe wait
```

There are definitely no issues from server side as our web app which uses `reactjs` and `socket-io client` library for web is able to connect to the server and pass messages.
I am not able to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: are you find any solution?

Comment: @balkaransingh No i gave up as it was a POC project

Answer (score 1):

if your baseURL contains an namespace, then it is the namespace issue, you have to put it into socket namespace like below:

```
let socket = socketManager.socket(forNamespace: "/yourUrlNamespace")
```

They didn't mention the namespace and domain criteria on socket.io-client-swift documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this problem recently. I was using socket.io ^4.4.1 on the server. But there was no mention of how to connect with the v4 server in the documentation, and the compatibility page was not loading, so I dig further.

I found out that "socket.io-client-swift" release version is 15, while 16 is probably still in development.

There is [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/blob/master/Usage%20Docs/Compatibility.md) compatibility table source code in which, sections 1 and 2 are required for version 15. I needed to add both the server and the client config for it to work.